# Converting Eclipse Maven Project into Eclipse Maven Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I need to convert my java maven project in eclipse into a maven dynamic web project.
My project is connected to an mercurial repository, so simply deleting and creating
a new project is not an option!

My project strucutre is:

```
project
    - src/main/java
    - src/main/resources
    - src/test/java
    - src/test/resources
    - pom.xml
```

I have to change the project type to a dynamic web project without deleting
my present project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the packaging type *war* to your POM.

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    ...
</project>
```

Then let the m2e plugin update your project. (Rightclick project -> Maven -> Update project...) The m2e plugin now rewrites the project meta-files (`.project` and `.classpath`, as well as files in the `.settings` folder). That's it. Now you have a web project.